# Does Brann Bronzebeard's ability activate as soon as he is played?

Tags: hearthstone

If I play Brann and then a minion with a Battlecry *in the same turn*, will the minion's Battlecry activate twice? I was playing and this didn't seem to work, which made me wonder if Brann has to be on the board from a previous turn (ie doesn't have the zzZZ exhaustion).

Comment: What minion did you play that didn't seem to work? What is something similar to what others have mentioned? ex. Big Game Hunter, where triggering twice has no additional effect. A minion destroyed twice is the same as one destroyed once.

Comment: I think the problem you may be having is that Bran doubles battlecry triggers but it does not let you choose new targets. That makes some triggers a bit redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes the double Battlecry Effect will trigger the same turn.** You can see some examples in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1nWKbdK3i4) youtube video. Also by personal experience i can vouch for that.

There are some Battlecrys which cannot be "doubled" i.e. Big Game Hunter will not allow you to destroy two minions. However [Samthere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11813/samthere) pointed out in the comment below

> It's not that BGH doesn't trigger twice, it's that a doubled player-targeted battlecry uses the same target for both effects. For example, Shattered Sun Cleric will end up giving a minion +2/+2. However, Hungry Crab targets. destroying only one murloc in the end, but will get +4/+4 for itself

Feel free to leave a comment so we can clear out what happend when you played.

Comment: It's not that BGH doesn't trigger twice, it's that a doubled player-targeted battlecry uses the same target for both effects. For example, Shattered Sun Cleric will end up giving a minion +2/+2. However, Hungry Crab targets. destroying only one murloc in the end, but will get +4/+4 for itself.

Comment: @Samthere oh i didn't know that, i'll copy it into the answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Brann will still work. Like every other ability in the game, Brann's ability still works while he has summoning sickness. There are two possibilities as to why Brann didn't work.

The first and most likely is that Brann only causes the battlecry to trigger twice. It doesn't allow you to select a new target for the second trigger so targeted battlecries will hit the same minion. This might be useful e.g. Abusive Sargent, or might have no additional effect e.g. Big Game Hunter. This can also apply to random target minions such as Stampeding Kodo- due to the order of effects, it can hit the same minion twice.

The second is that the minion didn't actually have Battlecry. Combo and Choose One minion abilities are similar to battlecries but for Brann's ability they are not.

Comment: "similar to battlecries battlecries". Did you just play Brann? :D

Comment: @Kappei Who knows what typos we'll uncover?